# Adding another Name for custom field in wordpress function.php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

A basic question for wordpress wizard, what is the proper way to add another name of field in the custom field section through function.php as indicated on the screenshot.. thanks
[Custom field section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdBcv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `add_post_meta()` function on a dummy post like this:

```
<?php add_post_meta( 68, 'my_key', 47 ); ?>
```

Where `68` is the ID of the dummy post, `my_key` is the name and `47` is the value, which is irrelevant but required.

See the [relevant article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) on the WordPress Codex for more.

I'm wondering, why would you want to add it through `functions.php`?